# Failed when calling variable from another class. (JAVA)

Tags: java, android, class, gps, location

I am newbie for java programming. I met some problem here, can anyone give some comment? When I check in the `onLocationChanged()`. There is desired value for `lngpoint` and `latpoint`. But when I called it to another method, `loadcoordinate()`, `loc.latpoint` and `loc.lngpoint` will become zero? Why?

Edited..basically my code is like this:

```
public class Testgpslocation extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    final Button gpsButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.gpsButton);
    LocationManager a = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    a.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, new MyLocationListener());
    gpsButton.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){
            LoadCoords();
        }});
}
MyLocationListener loc;
public void LoadCoords(){
loc = new MyLocationListener();

    String message = String.format(
            "wao New Location \n Longitude: %1$s \n Latitude: %2$s",
            loc.latpoint, loc.lngpoint
    );
    Toast.makeText(Testgpslocation.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    TextView latText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.latText);
    TextView lngText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lngText);


    double latitude = loc.latpoint;
    double longtitude = loc.lngpoint;
    latText.setText(Double.toString(latitude));
    lngText.setText(Double.toString(longtitude));
}
```

In another class:

```
private class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {
    private double latpoint;
 private double lngpoint;

public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    this.latpoint = location.getLatitude();
    this.lngpoint = location.getLongitude();
    String message = String.format(
            "New Location \n Longitude: %1$s \n Latitude: %2$s",latpoint, lngpoint
    );
    Toast.makeText(Testgpslocation.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String arg0, int arg1, Bundle arg2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}
}
```

}

Comment: What are you trying to do with the line "loc.latpoint, loc.lngpoint;"

Comment: Check out this site for some great Java tutorials. They walk you through end explain all you need to know about class, method and variable inheritance and they also do an Android lab at the end.

http://www.wibit.net/curriculum/courses/programming_java

Comment: hi justin, i want to called the variable from another class...in android. i need to use the updated coordinate on another class..

Comment: hi span...i am read the boos and tutorial but i still having this problem..so i do hope that any1 can give help specific on this problem...appreciate so much^^

Comment: Please work on your terminology: you can not call a variable. A variable is either read or assigned to (or you can say: accessed).

Comment: Angel O'Sphere thanks...so is there anyway i can do some kinds of work like code above?

Answer (score 1):

I belive MyLocationListener loc should be defined in the class scope and not in the construtor, like this

```
Public class A{
 MyLocationListener loc;
    public void loadcoordinate(){
          loc = new MyLocationListener();
        loc.latpoint, loc.lngpoint;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is on this line:

```
MyLocationListener loc = new MyLocationListener();
    loc.latpoint, loc.lngpoint;
```

Did you intend to do this?:

```
MyLocationListener loc = new MyLocationListener(loc.latpoint, loc.lngpoint);
```

Also, did you intend to capitalize "Public" on the very first line of your code? Is that even valid

Comment: thanks for ur reply..but i think this doesnt work because i didnt use any argument in MyLocationListener....so i have no write like this:

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
public class Testgpslocation extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
MyLocationListener loc;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    final Button gpsButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.gpsButton);
    LocationManager a = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    loc = new MyLocationListener();
    a.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, loc);
    gpsButton.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){
            LoadCoords();
        }});
}


public void LoadCoords(){


    String message = String.format(
            "wao New Location \n Longitude: %1$s \n Latitude: %2$s",
            loc.latpoint, loc.lngpoint
    );
    Toast.makeText(Testgpslocation.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    TextView latText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.latText);
    TextView lngText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lngText);


    double latitude = loc.latpoint;
    double longtitude = loc.lngpoint;
    latText.setText(Double.toString(latitude));
    lngText.setText(Double.toString(longtitude));
}
```

Comment: but when i send the lat and log from eclipse to emulator..the toast at onLocationChnaged() is show the right value. But when i press the button, the toast at LoadCoords() show zero...isnt it should follow the value in onLocationChanged()?

Comment: thanks i think i solve already. it is necessary give an initial  value
      public class Testgpslocation extends Activity {
 
 private double latpoint = 100.234444;
    private double lngpoint = 40.000000 ;
         ...}
thanks^^

Comment: You can also use the [LocationManager.getLastKnownLocation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#getLastKnownLocation(java.lang.String)) to get the last known location. Please also check the following link [GetLastKnownLocation vs. requestLocationUpdates](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/f88dbabaefa2178c)